# Add value to input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add value to input field by clicking on choices that are open on click.
I have this html that output input field

```
<div class="country first-country col-md-3">
                <input type="text" id="country1" placeholder="Select country/region" value="">
                    <ul id="country-list" class="country-list">
                      <li><a href="#">Spain</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">France</a></li>
                    </ul>
</div>
```

and when you click on input field, dropdown with choices is opened, and then when I click on Spain, value spain should be added to input.

```
$('.country-list').hide();
$( ".first-country").find('input').focus(function() {
        $('.country-list').show(300);
    });
$( ".first-country").find('a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        var text = $this.text();
        $( ".first-country").find('input').attr('value', text);;
        $('.first-country #country-list').hide(300);
    });
```

That all works fine,but when I try to type something on input field (for example blabla, and then I click on dropdown for example Spain, value attribute is changed, but blabla is still written on input, and js output that as a value, not the string from value attribute.

What I am doing wrong.
Here is working fiddle if it is easier to understand what I am having trouble with.

[wroking fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/unv219as/12/)

Thanks

Comment: what does CSS has to do with this? (in the tags)

Comment: Hi `val()` is the correct function to add a value to an input not `text()` http://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: text() is used to take text from a tag on click, and this $( ".first-country").find('input').attr('value', text);; is where that text is added to input value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is in this line:

```
$( ".first-country").find('input').attr('value', text);;
```

In order to set/get the input value you need to use [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

I would suggest to change this selector (the IDs must be unique):

```
.first-country #country-list
```

to:

```
#country-list
```

And instead of:

```
$( ".first-country").find('input')
```

you can reduce to:

```
$( ".first-country input")
```

The snippet:

```js
$('.country-list').hide();
$( ".first-country input").focus(function() {
    $('.country-list').show(300);
});
$( ".first-country").find('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    var text = $this.text();
    $( ".first-country input").val(text);
    $('#country-list').hide(300);
});
```

```css
.country input {
    color: #2980B9;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 27px;
    padding: .5rem .5rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="country first-country col-md-3">
    <input type="text" id="country1" placeholder="Select country/region" value="">
    <ul id="country-list" class="country-list">
        <li><a href="#">Spain</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">France</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add one line to your javascript:

```
$('.country-list').hide();
$( ".first-country").find('input').focus(function() {
        $('.country-list').show(300);
    });
$( ".first-country").find('a').click(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        var text = $this.text();

        $( ".first-country").find('input').attr('value', text);
        $( ".first-country").find('input').val(text); // <-- this one
        $('.first-country #country-list').hide(300);
    });
```

Comment: That is it. Thanks.